# What does it mean to marginalize and condition a causal graph?

Tags: probability, graph-theory, bayesian-network

In causal inference and Bayesian graphical models, the idea of "marginalization" and being "closed under marginalization and conditioning" is brought up and referred to in "Ancestral Markov Graphs" paper (https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-30/issue-4/Ancestral-graph-Markov-models/10.1214/aos/1031689015.full).

My question is:

1. how does this relate to marginalization and conditioning in probability distributions?
2. What does it mean intuitively for a graphical model to be "closed under marginalization and conditioning"?
3. What is an example of a graphical model that is not?

A related discussion on marginalization in probability distributions: [What does it mean to "marginalise out" something?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1511622/what-does-it-mean-to-marginalise-out-something)